# Sound but no Video

Tags: jquery, html, video, append

Trying to append a video to my HTML using jQuery.  I have got so far as that the sound of the video is playing, but just no video. Incredibly frustrating! Not sure if I haven't got something plugged-in or something.

Have had a good look on Stack, but to no avail.

HTML

```
<video id = "videoholder"></video>
```

jQuery

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#videoholder').append(
        '<video width="100%" autoplay>' + 
            '<source src="Images/event-video.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>' +
        '</video>');

});
```

Any kicks in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Cheers!

KM

Comment: Probably the video in the mp4 container is using a codec that is not supported by the browser you're using, but it's just guessing without having access to the video file.

Comment: append is basically adding video to a video...either you could make videoholder a div and then append ...or if you just want to make existing your code work...you need to append to the outer html using **$('#videoholder').parent().html(....)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are appending a video inside a video #videoholder...rather append video to a div #videoholder..

e.g.

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#videoholder').append(
            '<video width="100%" autoplay>' + 
                '<source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>' +
            '</video>');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body> 
    <div id = "videoholder"></video>
 

</body>
```

Comment: Awesome - thank you! In order to center this, is that done through the jQuery too, or CSS?

Comment: or simply **$('#videoholder').parent().html(
        '<video width="100%" autoplay>' + 
            '<source src="Images/event-video.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>' +
        '</video>')**

Comment: no..your existing code is enough...no need to worry about css

Comment: for center alignment & stuff..i suggest bootstrap

Comment: Any way to do it without Bootstrap? Trying to use jQuery only.

Comment: try **#videoholder{
        position : absolute;
        height : 90%;
        bottom: 5%;
    }**